# Correct way to organise this process in Node

Tags: node.js, express

I need some advice on how to structure this function as at the moment it is not happening in the correct order due to node being asynchronous.

This is the flow I want to achieve; I don't need help with the code itself but with the order to achieve the end results and any suggestions on how to make it efficient

1. Node routes a GET request to my controller.
2. Controller reads a .csv file on local system and opens a read stream using fs module
3. Then use csv-parse module to convert that to an array line by line (many 100,000's of lines)
4. Start a try/catch block
5. With the current row from the csv, take a value and try to find it in a MongoDB
6. If found, take the ID and store the line from the CSV and this id as a foreign ID in a separate database
7. If not found, create an entry into the DB and take the new ID and then do 6.
8. Print out to terminal the row number being worked on (ideally at some point I would like to be able to send this value to the page and have it update like a progress bar as the rows are completed)

Here is a small part of the code structure that I am currently using;

```
const fs = require('fs');
const parse = require('csv-parse');

function addDataOne(req, id) {
  const modelOneInstance = new InstanceOne({ ...code });
  const resultOne = modelOneInstance.save();
  return resultOne;
}
function addDataTwo(req, id) {
  const modelTwoInstance = new InstanceTwo({ ...code });
  const resultTwo = modelTwoInstance.save();
  return resultTwo;
}

exports.add_data = (req, res) => {
  const fileSys = 'public/data/';
  const parsedData = [];
  let i = 0;
  fs.createReadStream(`${fileSys}${req.query.file}`)
    .pipe(parse({}))
    .on('data', (dataRow) => {
      let RowObj = {
        one: dataRow[0],
        two: dataRow[1],
        three: dataRow[2],
        etc,
        etc
      };
      try {
        ModelOne.find(
          { propertyone: RowObj.one, propertytwo: RowObj.two },
          '_id, foreign_id'
        ).exec((err, searchProp) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            if (searchProp.length > 1) {
              console.log('too many returned from find function');
            }
            if (searchProp.length === 1) {
              addDataOne(RowObj, searchProp[0]).then((result) => {
                searchProp[0].foreign_id.push(result._id);
                searchProp[0].save();
              });
            }
            if (searchProp.length === 0) {
              let resultAddProp = null;
              addDataTwo(RowObj).then((result) => {
                resultAddProp = result;
                addDataOne(req, resultAddProp._id).then((result) => {
                  resultAddProp.foreign_id.push(result._id);
                  resultAddProp.save();
                });
              });
            }
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      i++;
      let iString = i.toString();
      process.stdout.clearLine();
      process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
      process.stdout.write(iString);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      res.send('added');
    });
};
```

I have tried to make the functions use async/await but it seems to conflict with the fs.openReadStream or csv parse functionality, probably due to my inexperience and lack of correct use of code...

I appreciate that this is a long question about the fundamentals of the code but just some tips/advice/pointers on how to get this going would be appreciated. I had it working when the data was sent one at a time via a post request from postman but can't implement the next stage which is to read from the csv file which contains many records

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can make the following checks into one query:

`if (searchProp.length === 1) {`
`if (searchProp.length === 0) {`

Use upsert option in mongodb findOneAndUpdate query to update or upsert.

Secondly don't do this in main thread. Use a queue mechanism it will be much more efficient.
Queue which I personally use is Bull Queue.

https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull#basic-usage

This also provides the functionality you need of showing progress.

Also regarding using Async Await with ReadStream, a lot of example can be found on net such as : https://humanwhocodes.com/snippets/2019/05/nodejs-read-stream-promise/